# How safe are Objective-C categories?

Tags: objective-c

Objective-C categories are extremely useful, but there are some problems with this power. These come in basically two forms which I know of:

- Two categories attempting to add the same convenience method. In this case, it is undefined which one is used. If you are careful - not adding too many methods or using particularly common method names - the first problem should almost never be an issue.
- New methods being added to a class by a writer that clash with a category. In this case the category overrides the class method. Since the class may not be under my control, I am more worried about this problem.

Backporting changes should be fairly safe, but implementing interfaces or adding convenience methods seem more dangerous. I know that Cocoa seems to use it for convenience methods quite a lot, but then again the base class is under there control. I think maybe they are just using the categories to reduce dependencies - so a String class can have convenience methods for working in Cocoa, but if you don't use Cocoa, it isn't pulled in.

So, how safe are categories/what guidelines are there for keeping them safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, when extending code not under your control (e.g. Foundation), it's traditional to use a prefix or suffix on the method name to avoid these sorts of collisions.

Example from [Peter Hosey's perform on main thread category](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/prhperformonmainthread-category/):

```
@interface NSObject (PRHPerformOnMainThread)
- (id) performOnMainThread_PRH;
@end
```

It's not the most beautiful solution, but if you're worried about fragility it's a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

I found the [Google Objective-C Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Category_Names#Category_Names) useful and it includes a convention to help avoid the collisions you mention.

Comment: I've seen references to it a few times, but I haven't read all of it yet. I think I should.